# Can't ping machine after installing virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

I installed Virtual box V3.2 on a machine. Now I cannot ping that machine from another computer on the network.  I have confirmed that the IP address of the machine is same.

I can browse the internet and access other machines on the  network, from the machine on which I installed virtual box.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Is the ping timing out? or some other error?

Comment: Yes the ping is timing out.

Comment: Using the terms "Guest OS" and "Host OS" are helpful for differentiating between the systems.  Are you saying that you can't ping the Host OS with a different machine on your network?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to ping the Guest OS and you are using NAT for networking, it might not always work.  It was a limitation of ICMP protocol traffic in NAT mode for VirtualBox.

NAT in VirtualBox does have these limitations (per the [User Manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#nat-limitations)):

> There are four limitations of NAT mode
>   which users should be aware of:
>
> ICMP protocol limitations: Some
>   frequently used network debugging
>   tools (e.g. ping or tracerouting) rely
>   on the ICMP protocol for
>   sending/receiving messages. While ICMP
>   support has been improved with
>   VirtualBox 2.1 (ping should now work),
>   some other tools may not work
>   reliably.
>
> Receiving of UDP broadcasts is not
>   reliable: The guest does not reliably
>   receive broadcasts, since, in order to
>   save resources, it only listens for a
>   certain amount of time after the guest
>   has sent UDP data on a particular
>   port. As a consequence, NetBios name
>   resolution based on broadcasts does
>   not always work (but WINS always
>   works). As a workaround, you can use
>   the numeric IP of the desired server
>   in the \server\share notation.
>
> Protocols such as GRE are unsupported:
>   Protocols other than TCP and UDP are
>   not supported. This means some VPN
>   products (e.g. PPTP from Microsoft)
>   cannot be used. There are other VPN
>   products which use simply TCP and UDP.
>
> Forwarding host ports lower than 1024
>   impossible: On Unix-based hosts (e.g.
>   Linux, Solaris, Mac OS X) it is not
>   possible to bind to ports below 1024
>   from applications that are not run by
>   root. As a result, if you try to
>   configure such a port forwarding, the
>   VM will refuse to start.

Answer (score 0):

Networking within, to, or from a virtual machine can be a complicated topic. Please do your own homework/research first, then come back with specific questions if it still doesn't work.

Here is a good place to start:
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=virtualbox+networking

Comment: Thank you but the problem is to about pinging the virtual machine. The problem is that I cannot Ping the machine  on which Virtual Box application is installed.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have to bridge the Host OS network connection with the Virtual Box connection in order for the guest OS networking to work.