# Can't access my computer after installing VirtualBox on it

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ping

There was a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/172505/cant-ping-machine-after-installing-virtual-box) 2 years ago, but everyone confused guest/host OS.

After installing VirtualBox on my Windows 7 box, I can no longer ping it or access it from anywhere within the LAN.  To be clear, I cannot access/ping the `Host` machine.  I can still use my host to access any other computer on the network or browse the internet.

From what I can see, VirtualBox installed a virtual network card.
[image]

The moment I right click and disable it, my Host OS is suddenly accessible and can be pinged within the network.

How can I resolve this problem (short of uninstalling VirtualBox)?

Comment: What happens when you try to ping it? Does ARP work? Does a ping get sent?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The ping just times out.  As in `Request timed out`.

Comment: Right, but does the ping get sent? Does ARP work? What *happens*? (`Request timed out` is just telling you that you didn't get a reply. The next thing you have to do is look to see how far you got.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So I terminal into a random box on the network and attempt to ping my box (e.g. host box).  The ping fails with `Request timed out`.  I am not sure how to tell whether ARP works.  I can tell you that I can ping my host OS from the guest OS - that works fine.

Comment: Does the ping get sent though? Does the machine you are pinging receive the ping? Does it send a response? You need to do some troubleshooting.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How would I check whether the machine receives the ping?

Comment: Using any tool that has the ability to display received network packets. You might also want to check if the machine you did the ping from sent the ping packet.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I reinstalled VirtualBox, then messed with the virtual network card configuration and then all of a sudden ping worked.  I still can't tell what specifically caused it to work.

Comment: Not surprising, since you didn't know what wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are using VirtualBox in [Host-Only Network mode](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly). That means, that the VMs can communicate with each other and the host but not the outside world. Try changing the Network Settings to Bridge mode.

Comment: Do I change the network settings on the Settings for the Virtual Machine or in Preferences/Network in the VirtualBox Manager?  And specifically what do I change?

Comment: @AngryHacker: See the line in the linked-to instructions that start with "To change a virtual machine's virtual network interface to "host only" mode:" -- you can probably do something similar to put it into a non-"Host-only networking" mode.

Comment: @martineau That was the plan, but I can't find anywhere in the article an explanation on how to take the driver from host only mode.

Comment: @AngryHacker: right click the stopped VM, choose "Settings". In the new window select "Network" in the right column. In the right column where it says "Attached to" change from "Host-only Adapter" to "NAT" or "Bridge Adapter".

Comment: @Simon All that does is change the connection method on a specific Virtual Machine.  The actual network card is still Host Only (as u see in the screenshot).

Comment: @AngryHacker: The adapter will remain, it comes with VirtualBox. But by changing the network mode you make sure it is not used. Once that is done you can disable it by right clicking the adapter and selecting disable.

Answer (score 1):

The same situation happened on me as well.

I figured the VirtualBox adapter somehow must have higher priority than other LAN.

Try and see if this helps

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8698

Workaround -

1. Open up Network and Sharing Center
2. Click 'Change Adapter Settings'
3. Right click 'VirtualBox Host-Only Network', go to Properties
4. Double click "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)' under 'This connection uses the following items'.
5. In the Properties page, click "Advanced..."
6. In the "Advanced TCP/IP Settings", tab "IP Settings", uncheck the box marked "Automatic Metic" and type in 800 or higher

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become outdated. Please include the main points from the link within your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Workaround - 
1. Open up Network and Sharing Center 
2. Click 'Change Adapter Settings' 
3. Right click 'VirtualBox Host-Only Network', go to Properties 
4. Double click "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)' under 'This connection uses the following items'. 
5. In the Properties page, click "Advanced..." 
6. In the "Advanced TCP/IP Settings", tab "IP Settings", uncheck the box marked "Automatic Metic" and type in 800 or higher.